# Spring-data findFirstBy throws IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException?

Tags: java, spring

I want to use sql select by method name in spring-data.

The select should be ordered by price.

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    int name;
    BigDecimal price;
}

interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Long> {
    Product findFirstByNameOrderByPriceAsc(String name);
}
```

Result:

```
org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: result returns more than one elements; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements
```

Why? I exactly used the `findFirst()` method for this reason to just get the top result if more than one is found..

Comment: which version of springdata you are using?

Comment: @Tkachuk_Evgen spring-boot 1.9.1.RELEASE, thus spring-data-jpa-1.6.4.RELEASE

Comment: top and first are available from 1.7.1.RELEASE [Spring Data JPA Changelog](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-jpa/1.7.1.RELEASE/changelog.txt)

Comment: @Tkachuk_Evgen ok thanks, great. Though it would be helpful if an error message is thrown in versions below if some kind of findFirst() is detected. Most tutorials on the net don't mention version restrictions...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Top` and `First` keywords are available since `spring-data-jpa-1.7.1.RELEASE`. See [Spring Data JPA Changelog](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-jpa/1.7.1.RELEASE/changelog.txt) and [Limiting query results](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result)